# nominal value not declared in header, read Token[X], line Y. I keep getting this popup on my Weka

Tags: statistics, weka, data-mining

@relation WILEligibilityPerFaculty

@attribute YesFPW [Yes-Engineering,Yes-Computing&Informatics,Yes-HumanSciences,Yes-ManagementSciences,Yes-Health&AppliedSciences,Yes-NaturalResources&SpatialSciences]
@attribute NoFPW [No-Engineering,No-Computing&Informatics,No-HumanSciences,No-ManagementSciences,No-Health&AppliedSciences,No-NaturalResources&SpatialSciences]

@data

Yes-Engineering
Yes-Engineering
Yes-Engineering
No-Engineering
No-Engineering
No-Engineering
No-Engineering
Yes-Engineering
Yes-Engineering
No-Computing&Informatics,
No-Engineering

Comment: I looked up on similar questions.

Comment: I also went through the documentation but couldn't find the solution that works well with my problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intent correctly, you actually have one attribute, not two. That attribute is FPW and can have the value of "Yes..." or "No...".

I've rearranged your data below and it loads into Weka correctly.

```
@relation WILEligibilityPerFaculty

@attribute FPW {Yes-Engineering,Yes-Computing&Informatics,Yes-HumanSciences,Yes-ManagementSciences,Yes-Health&AppliedSciences,Yes-NaturalResources&SpatialSciences,No-Engineering,No-Computing&Informatics,No-HumanSciences,No-ManagementSciences,No-Health&AppliedSciences,No-NaturalResources&SpatialSciences}

@data

Yes-Engineering 
Yes-Engineering 
Yes-Engineering 
No-Engineering 
No-Engineering 
No-Engineering 
No-Engineering 
Yes-Engineering 
Yes-Engineering 
No-Computing&Informatics 
No-Engineering
```

But I may not be interpreting your intent correctly. It's possible that you want to know the department, and Yes/No. In this case, you should separate Department and Yes/No into separate attributes:

```
@relation WILEligibilityPerFaculty  

@attribute Department {Engineering, Computing&Informatics}  
@attribute YesNo {Yes, No}  
@data  

Engineering,   Yes
Engineering,   Yes
Engineering,   Yes
Engineering,   No
Engineering,   No
Engineering,   No
Engineering,   No
Engineering,   Yes
Engineering,   Yes
Computing&Informatics,  No
Engineering,  No
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I wanted to divide the sets into two parts like you did but I don't know how to use Weka to find all departments that are yes and know. Thus I'm kinda forcing it by doing it in the dataset. Regardless thanks for helping out!